# helm chart testing connection failed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have an http app, which listen on port 3000 (I get a route to check health).
I expose dockerfile 3000 port.
I create a helm chart with `helm create`
The only thing I modify is the service and tests.
Into service,  I set port to 443 (needed by my ingress) and targetPort to 3000.
Into tests pod, I modify the port too:

```
  containers:
    - name: wget
      image: busybox
      command: ['wget']
      args: ['mysvc:443']
  restartPolicy: Never
```

But get `Connecting to mysvc:443 (10.96.235.205:443) wget: can't connect to remote host (10.96.235.205): Connection refused` with https://github.com/helm/chart-testing during CI (GHA)

I can see my app logs, and probes works too (on 3000)
I don't inderstand what is wrong.

Thanks

Update: Add mysvc definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysvc
  labels:
    {{- include "mysvc_chart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: clusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - port: 50051
      targetPort: grpc
      protocol: TCP
      name: grpc
    - port: 21
      targetPort: ftp
      protocol: TCP
      name: ftp
    - port: 3001
      targetPort: metrics
      protocol: TCP
      name: metrics
  selector:
    {{- include "mysvc_chart.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

Update2: Using nmap, I can see

````
443/tcp  closed https```
````

Comment: What does helm have to do with this question? How does your service definition for `mysvc` look like?

Comment: Chart testing is from helm repo. I updated my post with mysvc definition

Answer (score -1):

The port from my deployment was wrong -*-*-*-*-